# Keep getting Error 500 - Symfony2

Tags: database, symfony

This is my first experience with Symfony.

The error I have is when I try to load the website I get

The server returned a "500 Internal Server Error"

This is from the log

```
request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception PDOException: "SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)" at /home/virtual/public_html/v2/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php line 36
```

I already checked the app/config/parameters.yml and I'm using the correct username and password.

If I try the app_dev.php page everything works fine.

Thanks

Comment: Mmmmm, is the db created? Did you gave to it the right permissions?

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear the cache :

- in console : php app/console cache:clear